# "Wrap" Flutter Web inside static page

Tags: flutter, ads, flutter-web

I wanted to ask if anyone knows whether it would be possible to kind of "wrap" a Flutter web project inside of a static page?

Just trying to figure out someway to implement Ads on a Flutter web app, would this approach be correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Host your flutter web app somewhere ([firebase](https://firebase.google.com), [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev))
2. Create your static page with an iframe element ([generator](https://ekiwi.de/tools/smalltools/iframemaker.php))
3. Host your static page somewhere